# Browserify building with dependencies that have require statements in try-catch block

Tags: npm, browserify, javascript

I'm trying to use timbre.js (npm version) with Browserify, but it has require statements for optional dependencies in a try statement ([see source here](https://github.com/mohayonao/timbre.js/blob/master/timbre.node.js#L64)). This breaks the browserify build with a message like

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'lame' from 'such/and/such/a/location'
```

It seems like [someone else was having the same problem a few months ago](https://github.com/mohayonao/timbre.js/issues/18), but is this really a problem with this particular library's implementation, or does this come up a lot with other libraries that have optional CommonJS-required dependencies?

I tried a browserify transform ('remove-try-require') that was supposed to strip require statements out of try blocks, but it didn't seem to work.

Is there a common practice for dealing with such things?  Is the try-catch require statement bad form? What other ways might one handle optional dependencies?

Thanks!

(P.S. - A quick solution would be to get those optional dependencies, but I don't want them.)

Comment: Could you compile it without them using the `-x` flag?

Comment: I added the -x flag, and it compiled, but the output wasn't correct; it gave this output: [http://pastebin.com/B5tgcGYD](http://pastebin.com/B5tgcGYD).  I tried making a simplified version of my project with just two files and timbre as the only dependency, and same thing.

Comment: I looked into a little more and discovered something else. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compile with the `--ignore-missing` flag to ignore them.

```
browserify timbre.node.js --ignore-missing
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I just joined and don't have enough points to up your answer :)

Comment: Oh, but I can hit the check box.

Comment: Just a note, though, for people specifically having problems with timbre: You'll need to be pointing at timbre.dev.js (at least as of v14.6.23) if it's being built for the browser. timbre.node.js is not for the browser and will cause errors.